# Non IP-based policy routing on home network across subnets

Tags: networking, router, iptables, ssl, subnet

I have two routers chained together on my home network. The first router is a Banana Pi running Bananian. The only device connected to it (via its WAN port) is a DD-Wrt router, through which all of my devices connect:

Internet --> Cable Modem --> Banana Pi --> Router --> client devices

Thus, the Banana Pi and Router are on different subnets.

The banana Pi is being used as a transparent proxy and is currently intercepting all HTTP traffic, no problem. I'd like to intercept HTTPS traffic through it as well, but only for particular client devices. All other clients should be forwarded in the usual manner.

I could obviously do this by adding specific iptables rules to the Banana Pi to reroute port 443 requests to another port. However, my understanding is that this would require hard coded IP addresses and because the home router is using DHCP, these ip addresses could change at any time.

The Pi IP is 192.168.101.1, while the router IP is 192.168.1.1. I have tried setting the subnet mask on the Banana Pi to 255.255.0.0 to see if I could merge the networks, but doing this breaks most communication between the devices (with the exception of DHCP requests, which seems to still work ok in such a case).

Is there another way for the Banana Pi to be able to reliably route SSL traffic for selected clients other than resorting to IP address?

Comment: Can you use a DHCP reservation for the selected clients? Maybe check this out https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP

Comment: This is what firewalls do. You set up a black list for your "particular client devices" and those IPs are blocked, the rest go through. If you don't want to specify IPs, how are you planning on determining which clients are ok and which clients are not? If you want to inspect packets at the port level, you need to find a firewall that is TCP aware, which means it needs to inspect above the IP layer. They exists, but I don't have any specific ones to suggests at the moment. But even then, you need some criteria to determine what clients on 443 are good and which ones are not...

Comment: As it is a home network, the possibilities for what I can do are not that restrictive. However, I don't know what possibilities (if any) there are for setting a non-IP based policy at the firewall. The issue here is that IP addresses could change, circumventing any policy at the firewall.

Now if I were to allow for the possibility of static IP addresses, I could build those rules into the firewall. Or perhaps even better, specific a particular range of IP addresses that are intercepted.